# Can't run window phone 7 app in release mode

Tags: windows-phone-7

I can deploy my app successfully in Debug mode for both Nokia 710 and Emulator. However, when I change to Release mode in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, the NullReferenceException was thrown at this line

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

in the file `App.xaml.cs`. The problem happens for both Nokia 710 and Emulator. One hypothesis is that VS has a bug causing `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached` return true while there is no real Debugger "attacted". Is there any suggestion to get around this problem?

Update: I try to comment everything in `if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)`. It doesn't throw exception anymore. All I got when deploy it is the black screen and my app doesn't run

Comment: Do you have a way to recreate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hesitating between whether I should delete this question or post the answer for it. Finally, I decided to keep it to help others won't make any noob mistakes like this.

The answer for this question is very simple. When I set Release mode, I should do following steps:

- Build>Build Solution(F6)
- Build>Deploy Solution

That's it.

I made a mistake when press F5 and think it will deploy. Actually F5 is for debug only; therefore, it throws exception when can't find devices in debug mode.

Hope that help